# Is it possible through group policy to disable NLA for specific computer

Tags: windows, windows-xp, remote-desktop, windows-server-2019

I have a test environment consisting of a windows server (2019) install that I am trying to remote into from a windows xp sp2 install. (the reason I am doing this is simply a testing grounds to better understand how rdp works) Because the 'client' is XP SP 2, it doesn't have NLA with it's RDP. I know that in server 2019 NLA can be disabled totally with group policy, but what I am trying to achieve is disabling NLA ONLY for the windows XP SP2 client while retaining it for all other potential clients. Is this possible?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NLA option in the RDP server/service is a computer wide setting.
Disabling it for one user account to connect is not possible.

If your server(s) cannot have NLA disabled, I would recommend upgrading Windows XP to SP3 and enabling NLA ([link](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/24692-enable-network-level-authentication-nla-in-windows-xp)) or replacing it with a modern OS that supports NLA (amongst also not being a big security hole).

You can however use an alternate remote connection program to connect to the 2019 server, like VNC.
If your goal however is to learn more about RDP, then learning how Network Level Authentication works would be a wise starting point.

Comment: Thanks for your information, and yeah, while this is a testing environment, it's using constant variables, so changing to XP SP 3 is not an option. I will check out VNC connect though, thanks again for your help!